# Heap dump vs gcore dump and how to analyse the output

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, gdb, heap-dump

1. What is the difference between heap dump and gcore core dump ?
2. I am trying to analyze a running process that's growing in memory,
   If I do a core dump using gcore is it possible to convert it to heap dump ?
3. Are there any tools to analyse core/heap dumps other than gdb ?

Please feel free to correct me if I mixing things,

Comment: For 3, you may want to look at http://core-analyzer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this tool.